# Vector-Valued Functions

Tags: vectors

so I was given the question:

[image]

I assumed that I would do sin(7t)*cos(14t)=0. And solve for values of t that are in the interval. But how would I go about solving for these values?

Comment: When does $\sin(\theta)=0$? How about $\cos\theta=0?$ If either of them becomes zero, then the product of them together also becomes zero

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin(7t)\cos(14t)=0$ then we either have $\sin(7t)=0$ or $\cos(14t)=0$. Can you go on from here?

Comment: I was able to do the arithmetic, and got a final answer of pi/14 but I think is incorrect?

Comment: How did you get this?